# ArrayBlockingQueue: access to specific element

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have an ArrayBlockingQueue declared like this:

```
private BlockingQueue<E> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<E>();
```

now I have to access to a specific element of this queue. 
I have a method

```
public E takeElement(int j)
{
       //some code
}
```

and I have to take the j-element of the queue. How can I do that?? thx

Comment: If you need indexed access, why are you using a BlockingQueue? Its intended usage is processing items in order, with the possibility of waiting (blocking) if the queue is empty.

Comment: I have a queue and some method... somethimes I have to take head-element, somethimes I have to take j element.

Comment: What is the problem that you are really trying to solve?  You don't need to use BlockingQueue in a way that it was never meant to be used:  You need a different data structure/algorithm that solves some problem.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

```
E element = (E) queue.toArray()[j];
```

This will probably give a warning, but that is safe to ignore.

Comment: thx. Now I have the opposite question... what I have to do if I have to put an element in j-position??

Comment: You can't. If you need access like this, you shouldn't be using a `Queue`. Consider `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: I do this but I'm not sure that is a thread-dafe operation: queue.toArray()[j] = element;

Comment: Assinging an element to the array has no effect on the `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public E takeElement(int j) {
    for(int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        E e = queue.poll();
        if (i == j - 1) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or iterator based version:

```
public E takeElement(int j) {
    Iterator<E> it = queue.iterator();
    for(int i = 0; it.hasNext() && i < j; i++) {
        E e = it.next();
        if (i == j - 1) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: This would remove all elements in front of the sought element. I don't think that's what OP is looking for. Granted, it does adhere better to the purpose of `Queue`.

Comment: Poll remove all head element, I don't want this.

Comment: You really should be using a `List`. Just type `list.get(0);` when you need the head element.

Comment: It's a bit funny when a 57.2k user posts an answer that gets auto-flagged as Low Quality. Try explaining your answer a bit more in the future and it won't have to show up in LQ-queue.